# Compare two columns in a Sql table and select values from first table which is not present in second column

Tags: sql

Consider below table

```
ID|Parent_ID
1|0
2|0
3|1
4|1
5|1
6|2
7|2
8|3
9|3
10|5
11|7
```

The result required is that just compare column ID with column Parent_ID for values not present in Parent_ID.

```
Result
4
6
8
9
10
11
```

Comment: Your question could do with some formatting maybe?

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

You don't state RDBMS. This is standard SQL.

```
SELECT ID
FROM YourTable
EXCEPT
SELECT Parent_ID
FROM YourTable
```

Or

```
SELECT ID
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT Parent_ID
                  FROM   YourTable
                  WHERE  Parent_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using MySQL:

```
select  id
from    tbl
where   id not in (select parent_id from tbl)
```

If using Oracle

```
select  id
from    tbl
minus
select  parent_id
from    tbl
```

If using SQL Server then use EXCEPT as shown in previous answer

Answer (score 0):

This would work as well. See a demo [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e2b9a/6)

```
select id from table1 
where id not in 
(
  select t1.id from table1 t1
join table1 t2
on t1.id = t2.parent_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.ID FROM table AS T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table AS T2
ON T1.ID = T2.Parent_ID
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```